# Killing a process ends up hanging

Tags: c, process

I wrote this small program in C to kill a process given a user input pid.
However when I try running it, it seems to get hung up on the kill call indefinitely.

I'm not too sure where I went wrong, or if my testing is merely flawed, but I would love & appreciate some advice!

```
int main(void){
 int killpid;
 pid_t pid;

 printf("Input PID of process you would like to kill: \n");
 scanf("%d\n", &pid);

 killpid = kill(pid, SIGKILL);

 if(killpid == -1){
  printf("Termination failed!\n");
  return 0;
 }

 printf("Terminated process [%d]!", pid);
 return 0;
}
```

To test I used the ps -e command to list out all processes on my computer and ran my termination program with the pid of a text editor that was currently running. Is this a bad way to test, or maybe even the reason that my program is hanging? Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove the \n from your scanf function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `\n` solves the problem.
I'd also check the return value of `scanf` before doing something as dangerous as `kill`ing with `SIGKILL`:

```
//...
if(scanf("%d", &pid)<=0)
  return 1;
printf("Killing %d \n", pid);
//...
```